# Отсчёт миллисекунд

Tags: android, дата

Нужно выполнять ряд действий каждые 20 миллисекунд. Как это легче всего реализовать? (Пытался через `chronometer`, но, насколько я понимаю, он "тикает" только по секундам)

Answer (score 0):

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // тут ваше действие, которые вы хотите повторять.
    }
}, 0, 1000); //Тут вы указываете количество миллисекунд, 1000 milliseconds=1 second
```